# Angular Material Table, no restablece los items por página al borrar el filtro

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy usando el filtrado en Material tabs y me funciona bien, me halla los registros en todas sus columnas. Sin embargo cuando booro los datos del filtro y los dejo en blanco no me devuelve los items per page al estado natural.

Estado default:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Filtrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al borrar los datos de filtrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="filtrado($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input />
</mat-form-field>
```

La función en el TS:

```
            filtrado(event: Event) {
                this.dataSource = this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ofertas);
                const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
                this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
                if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
                this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

La paginación no funciona porque al hacer `new MatTableDataSource(this.ofertas)`, se usa un nuevo datasource y ese no tiene paginación.

Tu código se corrige agregando de nuevo el paginador:

```
filtrado(event: Event) {
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ofertas);

    this.dataSource.paginator = // agregar de nuevo el paginador

    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
        this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
}
```

Otra forma es no volver a crear el datasource  y solo establecer el filtro:

```
filtrado(event: Event) {
   const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
   this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

[Ejemplo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hki4s2?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts)